# Button to display modal is not doing anything after moving to plugin

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog

**SELF SOLVED:**

Simply needed to add document ready function to my script.

Originally I was using the same code but within my theme using:

```
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
    wp_enqueue_script('modal', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/modal.js', array(), '1.0', false);
});
```

and everything worked fine.

This morning I decided to move the script into my plugin and now the button does nothing.

I am getting nothing in console to help me debug this.

The script is registered and enqueued in the plugin:

```
wp_register_script( 'modal_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/modal.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modal_script' );
```

The button and classes:

```
<button onclick="anotherFunction()" class="trigger">Request Stamp</button>
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close-button">x</span>
```

The modal.js:

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

Nothing in console after button click to help me debug, network shows the script is loaded from the new plugin location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

to my js and everything works.